# Horizontal alignment of Expanderview items in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone

I want to align the contents or items of ExpanderView in horizontal layout instead of vertical layout. The ExpanderHeader is set dynamically and also its contents are added dynamically. 
The xaml part and CustomeItemTemplate in app.xaml is as below

```
    <toolkit:ExpanderView 
         Width="470" 
         Header="{Binding TaskName, Mode=TwoWay}"
          x:Name="taskNameExpander"
          Margin="5,10,5,10"
          Foreground="#FF677389" FontSize="24"   VerticalAlignment="Top"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          ItemsSource="{Binding dateTime}" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomItemTemplate}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
   </toolkit:ExpanderView>



<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomItemTemplate">

       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60" >
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Date, Mode=OneWay}"  
            TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF677389" Margin="0,6,0,0" Height="30" Width="100"/>
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Goldenrod" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF677389" Margin="0" Height="60" Width="150"/>
        </StackPanel>


  </DataTemplate>
```

Still i get the contents aligned vertically. Can someone point me what am i doing wrong here?

---

here is the sample code you have asked for

```
         <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
                            <ScrollViewer Width="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                            <toolkit:ExpanderView 
                                Width="1600" 
                                Header="{Binding TaskName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                x:Name="taskNameExpander" Margin="5,10,5,10" Foreground="#FF677389" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding dateTime}" 
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomItemTemplate}"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                                <toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>

                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemsPanel>

                            </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                            </ScrollViewer>


                        </Border>
```

and my app.xaml has CustomItemTemplate definition as below

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="100" >
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Date, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF677389" Margin="0,6,0,0" Height="30" Width="100"/>
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Goldenrod" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF677389" Margin="0" Height="60" Width="150">
            <TextBox.InputScope>

                <InputScope >
                    <InputScopeName NameValue="Number"></InputScopeName>

                </InputScope>

            </TextBox.InputScope>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I want to horizontally scroll only ExpanderView items. Rightnow it is scrolling but the whole ExpanderView is scrolling including its header. The header must be intact and only the items must scroll. How can i acheive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the ItemsPanel for the ExpanderView control.

```
<toolkit:ExpanderView 
                     Width="470" Height="100"
                      x:Name="taskNameExpander"
                      Margin="5,10,5,10"
                      FontSize="24" Background="White"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      ItemsSource="1 2 3 4" 
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomItemTemplate}"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemsPanel>
            </toolkit:ExpanderView>
```

Comment: That worked but the items in the Expanderview are going out of visible horizantally. I tried to put  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" for stackpanel but still the items are not scrollable horizontally. Any idea how to scroll the items horizontally inside a expanderviewer?

Comment: Try to put the ExpanderView inside the ScrollViewer

Comment: If we put ExpanderView inside scrollviewer it will scroll the complete expander including the header part. I just want to scroll the Expander items with the header intact. How is it possible?

Comment: can you share the sample code to understand your problem completely ?